# Charging 2S (8.4V) Lithium battery using MT3608 5V->8.4V DC-DC with Lipo protection

Tags: batteries, charging

I need a simple and cost-effective solution to charge an 8.4V battery from a 5V 2A AC-USB charger (or powerbank).

I am thinking of using this chain:
5V from USB -> MT3608 Step Up converter tuned to 8.4-8.5V -> 2S 8.4V BMS or balancing circuit -> 8.4V Lipo battery

Normally there also should be something like a specialized "charger" like TP4056 (for 4.2V) or TP5100 (for 8.4V).

So the questions are:

1. what will my circuit miss without this "charger". As far as I can see I can only go Constant Voltage, therefore my charging will not be optimal, but what will be the real drawback?
2. When "chargers" like TP5100 are charging in CC mode - are they able to boost output voltages temporarily to more than 8.4V?
3. One other drawback I see is that I do not have a current limiting in my schematic. But I am perfectly fine with 1-2A that USB charger can give. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Lithium batteries tend to be very intolerant of the wrong charging regime. Rarely can you just supply a given voltage. You NEED a charge circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't charge a battery with just a step-up converter and BMS.

The step-up converter will try to keep a constant 8.4V, and if your battery has only say 7.0V and connect that to the converter, the converter would not be able to output 8.4V no matter how much current it will output as the battery voltage can't immediately rise to 8.4V. And the converter will shut dow due to undervoltage or overcurrent.

You need a lithium battery charger.

1&3 ) Short circuiting constant voltage output to a battery won't work.

2. No a TP5100 will not boost, it only bucks so it needs more input voltage than the output battery voltage.